# why is my 126 datetime not coming back with a T in the middle?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've decided that I'll use 8601 datetimes for all the datetimes that I return from my app. Suddenly, in one particular proc, getdate() isn't returning a datetime with a T in the middle. **I should also mention that I'm converting the set containing a datetime to XML** using FOR XML PATH. Typically when I convert a table containing datetime to xml I get 8601 formatted dates. But in one case, I'm not.

```
select (cast(getdate() as datetime)) -- returns 2010-01-25 10:13:46.033
```

So I directly converted it like so:

```
select convert(datetime, getdate(), 126) -- returns 2010-01-25 10:14:35.923
```

But if I cast it to an nvarchar I get the T!!

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126) -- returns 2010-01-25T10:15:29.633
```

What's even stranger to me is that if I select several versions of this with a union, the T version disappears. But selecting without the union, the T version (last one) remains.

```
-- returns 4 rows of 2010-01-25 10:15:57.333
select getdate() union all 
select (cast(getdate() as datetime))  union all
select convert(datetime, getdate(), 126)    union   all
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126)
```

I really have no idea what could cause this to happen. I thought 8601 dates were locale-independent, so I don't think it's anything like that.

Reference ("yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm" for a 126): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up datetime values with formatted strings.

The first two examples doesn't return the date formatted in any way at all, it's just a `datetime` value. How the value is formatted into text is decided by how you display the value after getting it from the database. If you lived in a different country so that your default culture settings were different, the date could for example be displayed as `1/25/2010 10:14 AM` instead.

In the second example the format parameter (126) is ignored, as there is no formatting or parsing involved when converting from a `datetime` value to a `datetime` value.

The third example formats the `datetime` value into a string before it's returned from the database, that's why you get it in the format that the database uses.

If you use a union with difference data types, it's the [type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) that decides the type of the result. The `datetime` type has higher precedence than `nvarchar`, so it attempts to convert the `nvarchar` values to `datetime`.

Comment: Although (in the union example) if you put the nvarchar query first it will still convert everything to datetime .. weird .. (SQL SERVER 2005)

Comment: I think you're right, my test setup is not good. Still I was seeing weirdness out of my results (for the real proc). The issue was in the XML: if you do FOR XML PATH the converter puts in 8601 dates. I edited the question to include this. In my case the issue was that there was a datalayer that was converting datetimes differently than SQL would (some of the time).

Comment: @Gaby: That is correct. It's not the first result that decides the data type, it's the rules of type precedence. I changed that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert to datetime, you're not choosing a format - date, time, and datetime are all stored in an internal format.  Only when you convert to a string (char, varchar, nvarchar) does the format matter to the output.  In the other cases the format is being chosen by SQL Server implicitly, and it happens to be close but not identical to 8601.

Comment: OK then why would some of my procs return getdate() as 8601 format and others in the same format but without the T? Shouldn't getdate() always return the same thing regardless of which proc returns it?

Comment: getdate() isn't returning a string, it's returning a datetime object. When the datetime object gets converted to a string, that's when the formatting occurs. If you want your procs to be consistent, have them always return a string.

Answer (score 1):

`GETDATE()` already returns `DATETIME`, so this expression:

```
CONVERT(datetime, getdate(), 126)
```

does nothing.

You may substitute any other format option of even omit the `CONVERT` portion: the result will be the same.

The string representation of the `DATETIME` returned is chosen by the client, not the server.

Its internal representation is a `8`-byte integer, with the first `4` bytes denoting number of days from `1900-01-01`, and the second `4` bytes denoting the number of `1/300` seconds from midnight.

When you convert to an `NVARCHAR`, then the server makes the text representation and returns it as is. In this case, you see a `T` substituted by the server.

Comment: The issue here is that in some procs select getdate() is coming back in 8601 format and in other procs it's not.

Comment: `GETDATE()` returns a `8`-byte sequence. Any "coming back" happens only when the value is converted to a string (this may be done by the client).

Comment: It's weird that select getdate() was coming back with a T last week, but no T this week. Wonder how on earth that could have changed (something in SSMS settings I assume).

Answer (score 0):

operator precedence, in your union everything gets cast to a datetime since that is the first row. If you want the T then you need to cast to varchar but again you can't do this in a union since mixed datatypes will be cast to the same datatype (if it is possible)

This includes the T, a datetime itself is stored as 2 integers and has nothing to do with this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126)
```